# How to send a file to post method that accepts form data in python flask, and also how to retrieve file and other fields in the called method?

Tags: python, rest, flask, post, file-upload

I'm trying something like this.

Caller code -

```
files = {'file': open(file_name, 'rb').read()}
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=metadata, files=files)
```

Called method code-

```
        metadata = {}
        for key, value in request.form.items():
            metadata[key] = value
        print(metadata)
        print(type(metadata))
        print("Request data")
        print(request.data)
        print("Files")
        print(request.files)
        print(request.files is None)
        print('file' not in request.files)
```

The output in called method is empty

```
{}
<class 'dict'>
Request data
b''
Files
ImmutableMultiDict([])
False
True
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Hey did you find any solution to this? Would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
files = {'upload_file': open('file.txt','rb')}
values = {'DB': 'photcat', 'OUT': 'csv', 'SHORT': 'short'}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=values)
```

---

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    if uploaded_file.filename != '':
        uploaded_file.save(uploaded_file.filename)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```